# Android Camera Shutter Counter

Tags: android, api, android-camera

I wonder if there is any way to determine the **camera shutter counter** on an Android device. I want to know how often the camera has been used and how often the flash has been used. Is there any kind of API or system file I can use?

So far I checked [Camera class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).

Thanks in advance.

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in counter like that. You can add it in your custom ROM.

Note that camera may be used to capture still pictures, or to record video, or to display camera preview e.g. for some augmented reality game. The game could save the preview frames in some format, or not. Also, advanced cameras can provide 1080p high quality preview.

When you plan to add a counter, consider if you want to count number of times the camera was opened, or duration of camera being in preview mode, or number of preview frames processed.